# Clang Windows LD Set Library Path Not Work?

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang, lld

Compiling on windows with 6.0.0 or 6.0.1

ld.lld can't find the library in specified path.

This does not work:

`ld.lld Source.o -o Executable.exe -L"C:/Users/Username/Documents/" libcode.a`

But this does:

`ld.lld Source.o -o Executable.exe C:/Users/Username/Documents/libcode.a`

Am I doing something wrong here?
It works with gnu ld just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-l flag is required, omitting the "lib" prefix and extension.

ld.lld Source.o -o Executable.exe -L"C:/Users/Username/Documents/" -lcode